# Move all elements which satisfy some condition from one container to another, i.e. I'm looking for some kind of "move_if"

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Given

```
std::vector<T> first = /* some given data */, second;
```

I want to *move* all elements `e` which satisfy some condition `cond(e)` from `first` to `second`, i.e. something like

```
move_if(std::make_move_iterator(first.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(first.end()),
    std::back_inserter(second), [&](T const& e)
{
        return cond(e);
});
```

I wasn't able to establish this with the *algorithms library*. So, how can I do that?

Comment: How about [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) followed by [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Why do you think `remove_copy_if` does the job?

Comment: `copy_if` with `move_iterator`. Make sure your predicate is taking its argument by const ref.

Comment: @T.C. Right, that will move the elements to `second`. However, `first` still contains these elements (even if there data has been moved). So, how can I erase them from `first`?

Answer (score 43):

If the moved-from elements can stay where they are in `first`, then just use `copy_if` with `move_iterator`.

```
std::copy_if(std::make_move_iterator(first.begin()),
             std::make_move_iterator(first.end()),
             std::back_inserter(second), cond);
```

If the moved-from elements should be erased from `first`, I'd do

```
// partition: all elements that should not be moved come before 
// (note that the lambda negates cond) all elements that should be moved.
// stable_partition maintains relative order in each group
auto p = std::stable_partition(first.begin(), first.end(),
                               [&](const auto& x) { return !cond(x); });
// range insert with move
second.insert(second.end(), std::make_move_iterator(p),
                            std::make_move_iterator(first.end()));
// erase the moved-from elements.
first.erase(p, first.end());
```

Or `partition_copy` with a `move_iterator`, followed by assignment:

```
std::vector<T> new_first;
std::partition_copy(std::make_move_iterator(first.begin()),
                    std::make_move_iterator(first.end()),
                    std::back_inserter(second), std::back_inserter(new_first), cond);
first = std::move(new_first);
```

Comment: You don't have to invert `cond` in the middle case, you can use the range [`first.begin()`, `p`) instead of [`p`, `first.end()`), although I guess it saves on compacting the result

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `move_if` doesn't exist is because it would bloat the library. Either use `copy_if` with move iterator or write it yourself.

```
copy_if(move_iterator<I>(f), move_iterator<I>(l), out);
```

Here is an implementation by [Jonas_No](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/STL-moveif-algorithm-whats-your-take-on-it-) found at channel9.

```
template <typename FwdIt, typename Container, typename Predicate>
inline FwdIt move_if(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Container &cont, Predicate pred)
{
    if (first == last)
        return last; // Empty so nothing to move
    const size_t size = count_if(first, last, pred);
    if (size == 0)
        return last; // Nothing to move
    cont.resize(size);
    FwdIt new_end = first;
    auto c = cont.begin();
    for (auto i = first; i != last; ++i)
    {
        if (pred(*i)) // Should it move it ?
            *c++ = move(*i);
        else
            *new_end++ = move(*i);
    }
    return new_end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@T.C. has provided a perfectly working solution. However, at a first glance, one may not understand what the intend of that code is. So, it might be not perfect, but I tend to prefer something like this:

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class InputContainer, class UnaryPredicate>
OutputIt move_and_erase_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, InputContainer& c, OutputIt d_first, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    auto dist = std::distance(first, last);
    while (first != last)
    {
        if (pred(*first))
        {
            *d_first++ = std::move(*first);
            first = c.erase(first);
            last = std::next(first, --dist);
        }
        else
        {
            ++first;
            --dist;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Comment: iteratively calling `c.erase(first);` doesn't sound like the best idea for containers which store their elements in a continuous storage

Comment: and at first look `std::next(first, --dist);` looks like a bug, because you are setting `last` to position `current+(previous container size)-1`

Comment: Removing elements one by one not very performant. Each time the gaps will be closed by moving elements around. Therefore the accepted answer is the way to go.